# Access to vector underlying data in .natvis files for Visual Studio ImageWatch plugin

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, natvis

### The problem

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063272/vs-image-watch-extension-natvis-for-bitmapinfoheader) question, I am trying to use the [ImageWatch](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) plugin for my own defined type `MyImageClass`. ImageWatch is a Visual Studio Plugin that allows you to view Images in a graphical representation while debugging code. You can write .natvis files to add support for custom defined classes.

```
struct MyImageClass
{
  uint32_t width;
  uint32_t height;
  std::vector<char> image_data;
}
```

The ImageWatch plugin expects a `char*` type for the image data, however I am storing my data in a `std::vector<char>`.
My .natvis file, is quite simple, (you can skip it, only for completeness)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010"> 
  <UIVisualizer ServiceId="{A452AFEA-3DF6-46BB-9177-C0B08F318025}" Id="1"
            MenuName="Add to Image Watch"/> 
  <Type Name="MyImageClass">
    <UIVisualizer ServiceId="{A452AFEA-3DF6-46BB-9177-C0B08F318025}" Id="1" />
  </Type>

  <Type Name="MyImageClass">
    <Expand>
      <Synthetic Name="[type]">
        <DisplayString>UINT8</DisplayString>
      </Synthetic>
      <Item Name="[channels]">1</Item>
      <Item Name="[width]">width</Item>
      <Item Name="[height]">height</Item>
      <Item Name="[planes]">1</Item>
      <Item Name="[data]">image_data</Item>
      <Item Name="[stride]">width</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>  
</AutoVisualizer>
```

But the following line I am struggeling with `<Item Name="[data]">image_data</Item>`. The image data assignment does not work, I cannot see the image in the viewer. Instead I get the message "invalid". Clearly, this is because `image_data` is a `std::vector<char>` and not `char*`.

### What I have tried

I have tried many different things inside the `<Item Name="[data]">image_data</Item>` tag to access the vectors underlying `char*` data pointer, but none work:

- `image_data`
- `image_data.data()` Apparently no functions may be called in .natvis Files, Natvis output: Error: Side effects are not supported in this context.
- `image_data._Myfirst` (Similar to
  [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2)
  Section "ArrayItems Expansion") Natvis output: Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

### What works, but isn't the ideal solution

As a workaround and to see if my data is correct I have added a `char*` to the struct and then assign it the vectors underlying data.

```
struct MyImageClass
{
  uint32_t width;
  uint32_t height;
  std::vector<char> image_data;
  char* image_data_ptr;
};
```

and then

```
image_data_ptr = image_data.data();
```

The .natvis file is changed accordingly

```
<Item Name="[data]">image_data_ptr</Item>
```

This works, and I can see the image in ImageWatch. However, I would hate to introduce an extra variable, only for the purpose of the VS debugger.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the data of the vector can be analyzed the following way:

```
<Item Name="[data]">image_data._Mypair._Myval2._Myfirst</Item>
```

I found this out by analyzing the natvis debug output for a different vector.

### Edit:

As I realized, this is implementation specific. The above solution works well under VS2015. In VS 2012, the solution which didn't work above

```
<Item Name="[data]">image_data._Myfirst</Item>
```

works quite well.

Answer (score 5):

I've found an even "better" solution without the need for an extra pointer in the struct:

```
<Item Name="[data]">&amp;image_data[0]</Item>
```

Which evaluates to code:

```
&image_data[0]
```

Effectively, this returns the address of the first element of the vector (and vector internally uses an array, so you're basically returning a pointer to the array)